# Program to track  and analyze usage

Tags: software-rec, time, productivity

I would like to get my computer usage statistics (what programs I ran, for how long and etc. More is better).

I used to use [wakoopa](http://wakoopa.com) but I'm not willing to throw statistics out to the web. I've tried hamster but I always forgot/haven't set tracking time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into [GnoTime](http://gttr.sourceforge.net/).

Tracking processes that run on the computer is easy and there are lots of profiles that will tell you all about what is running on your system. The problem is it sounds like you want to track your attention to these programs, and this is less intuitive. For this reason you probably want to look into time tracking programs more than you do program tracking.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track your daily activities, track time for clients, or other tasks, you can try using [employee software for time tracking](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/04/windows/business/download-time-doctor-free.html). This is a fantastic tool and good alternative to Wakoopa and Hamster time tracker.

Comment: Judging on video intro - it should be annoying as hell. Its for enterprise usage. I need for personal usage.

Comment: I wonder why this was modded down... if it can do the job...

Comment: It appears to be a ms windows program....

Comment: @mattdm There's a [linux version](http://www.timedoctor.com/downloads/linux32/stable/)